# How to render a ejs view after sending POST form data to the server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, postgresql, ejs

I am trying to create an authentication system using EJS and PG database, but I am having trouble getting the routing and rendering to work.

In my `index.html` I have an anchor element that points to `signup.html`, which works. In `signup.html` I have a login form, but then when I try to submit it, I get an HTTP 405 error.
How do I properly set up the routing between `index.html`, `signup.html`, and `app.js` (where the authentication logic happens)?

index.html:

```
<a href="signup.html" class="auth-link">Sign Up</a>
```

signup.html:

```
<form action="/users/register" method="POST">
```

app.js:

```js
app.get("/users/register", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Even though the question is not well written, it's not a big issue to solve. In `signup.html` you have the form `<form action="/users/register" method="POST">` which makes a **POST** request. But in your `app.js` you check for a **GET** request. So instead of `app.get( ... )` write `app.post( ... )`.